# Python открытие файлов zip с паролем по цепочке

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

У меня есть file.zip. В нем находятся:
1)запороленный 1.zip 
2)пароль для него (для 1.zip) в 1.txt.  

В 1.zip:
1)запороленный 2.zip 
2)пароль для него (для 1.zip) в 2.txt.  

и так до 100.
Внутри 100.zip есть файл 101.txt в котором находится нужный мне текст

Как для этого написать скрипт на python?

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается? Где основная проблема? Здесь принято показывать код - то что вы попробовали сделать (и где у вас возникла проблема)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы расшифровать и разархивировать файлы по цепочке, можно простой цикл использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

n = 101
archive, password = ZipFile('file.zip'), None
for i in range(1, n):
    archive, password = (ZipFile(BytesIO(archive.read(f'{i}.zip', password))),
                         archive.read(f'{i}.txt', password))
print(archive.read(f'{n}.txt', password).decode())
```

`{i}.zip` содержит `{i+1}.txt` и `{i+1}.zip`.
`{i}.txt` содержит пароль для содержимого `{i}.zip` (используется при чтении `{i+1}.txt`).
`file.zip` не зашифрован.

Answer (score 3):

Вот вариант "в лоб" с рекурсией и чтением ZIP файлов в памяти (не распаковывая на диск):

```
import io
import zipfile

def search_zip(zf, pwd=None):
    assert isinstance(zf, zipfile.ZipFile), "expect [zipfile.ZipFile] instance"
    files = [f.filename for f in zf.filelist]
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.txt'):  # найден ".txt"
            # читаем пароль
            new_pwd = zf.read(f, pwd)
            zip_fn = f.replace('.txt', '.zip')
            # если на текущем уровне существует `.zip`, то идем глубже
            if zip_fn in files: 
                data = zf.read(zip_fn, pwd)
                print("found [{}], password: [{}] - going deeper...".format(zip_fn, new_pwd ))
                return search_zip(zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(data)), new_pwd)
            else: # это "дно" - возвращаем содержимое `.txt` файла
                return new_pwd
```

Использование:

```
In [100]: search_zip(zipfile.ZipFile(r'D:\temp\aaa\file.zip'))
found [f1.zip], password: [b'pwd1'] - going deeper...
found [f2.zip], password: [b'pwd2'] - going deeper...
found [f3.zip], password: [b'pwd3'] - going deeper...
Out[100]: b'Secret Text'
```